# Why use strings rather than direct method calls to trigger an action in a Redux store?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

What is the advantage of passing strings to a Redux store in order to trigger an action rather than simply specifying additional methods on the store and calling those methods directly? Seems like the latter would allow one to avoid a bunch of `if` or `switch` statements. For example, from the Redux docs:

```
function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          text: action.text,
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    case 'COMPLETE_TODO':
      return state.map((todo, index) => {
        if (index === action.index) {
          return Object.assign({}, todo, {
            completed: true
          })
        }
        return todo
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

An alternative:

```
const todos = {
  addTodo: function(state, action) {
    return [
      ...state,
      {
        text: action.text,
        completed: false
      }
    ]
  },

  completeTodo: function(state, action) {
    return state.map((todo, index) => {
      if (index === action.index) {
        return Object.assign({}, todo, {
          completed: true
        })
      }
      return todo
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think probably the main reason is to support functionality like:

> record and replay user sessions, or to implement hot reloading with time travel

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/ReducingBoilerplate.md#actions

Thanks to @markerikson for pointing out this entry in the [FAQ](http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#why-should-type-be-a-string-or-at-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants):

> ## Why should "type" be a string, or at least serializable?
>
> As with state, having actions be serializable enables several of Redux's defining features, such as time travel debugging, and recording and replaying actions.

You might also find this discussion on serializability of actions interesting: [reactjs/redux#437](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/437).

> Seems like the latter would allow one to avoid a bunch of `if` or `switch` statements.

That's easy enough to avoid anyway:

```js
var actions = {
  ADD_TODO (state, action) {
    return [
      ...state,
      {
        text: action.text,
        completed: false
      }
    ]
  },

  COMPLETE_TODO (state, action) {
    return state.map((todo, index) => {
      if (index === action.index) {
        return Object.assign({}, todo, {
          completed: true
        })
      }
      return todo
    })
  },
};

function todos(state = [], action) {
  var handler = actions[action.type];
  if (handler) return handler(state, action);
  return state;
}
```

It's also discussed in the Redux docs: [Reducing Boilerplate](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ReducingBoilerplate.html).

Comment: And also now in the Redux FAQ: [Why should "type" be a string?](http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#why-should-type-be-a-string-or-at-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants)